# Increase circle radius on drag until event is fired (D3js)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a `circle` selection in D3 whose radius I would like to increase by increments of 1 starting with the `dragstart` event and ending with the `dragend` event. For example, if the drag is active for 100ms, I'd like the radius to increase by 1 pixel, and if it the drag is active for 400ms, I'd like the radius to increase by 4 pixels.

This may well be a pure JavaScript question, but I'd like to glean any D3 best practices in the process.

Here is my JS/D3:

```
function increaseHoleRadius() {
    // Increase radius of hole until dragend() runs
    // e.g. -> hole.attr('r', count++)
}

function dragstart() {

    // begin increasing radius of "hole" selection
    increaseHoleRadius();
}


function dragmove() {

    // drag circle element

    var m = d3.mouse(this);

    currentX = m[0];
    currentY = m[1];

    circle.attr({
            cx: m[0],
            cy: m[1]
        });

}

function dragend() {

    // set hole selection back to initial radius

    hole.attr({
            r: 20
        });

}
```

Here is a [working codepen](http://codepen.io/himmel/pen/jbbPOo). Note that in this example the radius of `hole` only increases *while* the element is being dragged. I'd like the radius to increase constantly until the drag event ends.

Comment: It looks like it works; what's the question? How do you desire your solution to differ from the working example provided?

Comment: The hole only increases in size *while the circle element is being dragged*, I'd like it to increase constantly before the drag is released.

Comment: Ah, okay, that makes sense. You'd almost be required to use setTimeout for something like that.

Comment: The below answer did exactly that, but it doesn't allow for a smooth transition.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that, but it looks like you might be able to hack something together by setting an linear transition in CSS with a speed that matches the growth rate of the radius divided by the timing between setTimeout calls, to eliminate the jitter. I don't know if it's possible, but it's what I'd try next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call periodically the `increaseHoleRadius` function, while dragend event has not occured.

One of solution is to call recursively the `increaseHoleRadius` function with a setTimeout of 100ms :

```
function dragstart() {
    increase = true;
    increaseHoleRadius();
}

function increaseHoleRadius() {
    if (increase) {
        console.log("increase");
        hole.attr({
            r: function() {
                return count++;
            }
        })
        setTimeout(increaseHoleRadius, 100); // 100ms
    }
}

function dragend() {
    console.log('dragend');
    increase = false; // stop the increaseHoleRadius function
    [...]
}
```

Here is the full codepen solution : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pjjPgM?editors=001

Comment: This works, but I'd like the radius to tween or transition between values so that it increases smoothly.